# Domain of holomorphicity of $f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z+1}$

Tags: analyticity

Domain of holomorphicity of $$f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z+1}$$

Is this simply everywhere, because there is no $\bar z$ dependence?

Comment: It's holomorphic everywhere it is defined, which is everywhere that $e^z \neq -1$.

Answer (score 3):

What happens if $z=(2n-1)\pi i$?